# why is the hash value missing in the below code

Tags: perl, hash, mojo-useragent

I wanted to do a POST request to jira and jfrog. while I try to get the values of the hash within the loop am not able to get the value the second time. I try to read the variable(API token instead of password) from env, if not set it will pass the username and password.

```
my %urls = (
    'jira' => {
        'url' => 'https://jira.com:123/rest/api/2/issue/', 
        'token' => 'JIRA_TOKEN'
    },
    'jfrog' => {
        'url' => 'https://jfrog.com/artifactory/api/storage/path/to/artifacts',
        'token' => 'JFROG_TOKEN'
    }
);

my $jira_ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
for my $outer_elem ( keys %urls ) {
    for my $inner_elem ( keys %{$urls{$outer_elem}} ) {
        # print $inner_elem;
        if ( !$ENV{$urls{$outer_elem}{'token'}} ) {
            print "Enter username : \n";
            my $username = <STDIN>;
            chomp($username);
            my $passwd = read_password("Enter Password: ");
            $url = Mojo::URL->new($urls{$outer_elem}->{'url'})
            ->userinfo($username.':'.$passwd);
        }
        else {
            if ( $inner_elem eq "jira" ) {
                $tx->req->headers->authorization (
          "Bearer $ENV{$urls{$outer_elem}->{'token'}}"
               );
                $url = Mojo::URL->new($urls{$outer_elem}->{'url'})
            }
        }
        print $outer_elem . "\n";
        print "logging in to $urls{$outer_elem}->{'url'}\n";
        $tx = my $ua->get($url); # <--- line 170
        my $res = $tx->res->code;
        print $res;
        last;
    }
}
```

I get below output

```
D:\scripts>perl emtf.pl
jira
Can't call method "get" on an undefined value at emtf.pl line 170.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is:

> Can't call method "get" on an undefined value

And the line of code that generates the error is:

> ```
> $tx = my $ua->get($urls{$outer_elem}->{'url'});
> ```

The error means that `$ua` contains `undef` when you try to call the `get()` method on it. That's because you create a new variable called `$ua` on this line of code - that's what `my` does. And because you don't assign a value to this new variable, it will contain `undef`.

I'm not sure why the `my` is there. And I'm not sure I really understand how your code is supposed to work. There's another variable called `$ua` that is defined but not used in the anonymous subroutine that's defined a few lines above (`my( $ua, $tx ) = @_;`) but that variable doesn't exist outside that subroutine.

Did you, perhaps mean the line to use `$jira_ua` instead:

```
$tx = $jira_ua->get($urls{$outer_elem}->{'url'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed ````my $ua```` to  ```$jira_ua```. My assumption was the has variable is empty. The code works now. The code inside else is from mojo::useragent for non blocking https requests.

Comment: @Itsme *My assumption was the hash variable is empty.* That's why it's important to read the error message very carefully. It says you're calling a method **on** an undefined variable.

Comment: ```Use of uninitialized value $url in pattern match (m//) at C:/StPerl530_x64/perl/vendor/lib/Mojo/UserAgent/Transactor.pm line 119.
Use of uninitialized value $url in concatenation (.) or string at C:/StPerl530_x64/perl/vendor/lib/Mojo/UserAgent/Transactor.pm line 119.
``` since the values are read in random, I get the above error sometimes if Jira comes first but for jfrog this isn't seen. do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Itsme: If you have a new question, it's probably best to post it as a new question.